# Настройка url в django

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять, почему не могу url привязать?
urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import *
from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('', # error here, why?
    ('^hello/$', hello),
)
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Здравствуй, Мир")
```

Делал все по книге, один в один.

Comment: Show us your error please.

Comment: SyntaxError at / Non-ASCII character '\xc7' in file c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\mysite\mysite\views.py on line 4

Comment: да, файл был не в той кодировке, упустил момент, а не подскажите как настроить url для главной странице, т.е. для '/' ?
пробовал как-то так ('^/', index) - не сработало...

Comment: Попробуйте '^\$', загляните на сайт djangoproject, там много примеров. Если ответ вам пригодился, думаю, с таким рейтингом знаете, что делать.

Comment: Да, знаю, спасибо что быстро мне уточнили пару моментов по django!

Comment: Ваша проблема, скорее, болезнь Python, а не только django.

Comment: В смысле? :)

Comment: Проблема с кодировками, это общая болезнь Python, поэтому и приходится с этим бороться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас файл, видимо, сохранен не в той, что нужно кодировке. Или копировали откуда-то, затесался лишний символ. Если вручную не писали этот код, перепишите с нуля. Это исключительно проблема кодировки, так как у меня ваш вариант работает просто скопированный отсюда.

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример живого корневого урлса включающего админку:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: В `urlpatterns` все правильно и так.